Adding visual feedback to my ListBox when dragging selected ListBoxItem up or down
In my WPF application I am displaying a ListBox which supports dragging and dropping its items which allows the user to rearrange the list. It works 100% however it doesn't give the user feedback on where the list box item is going to be placed. The only thing the user does sees is a little box icon next to the cursor when the drag event is happening.
Here is a design of what I am going for:

This is how I have my application set up:
    <ListBox x:Name="lbItems" AllowDrop="True" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
                    <Image Width="64" Height="64" Stretch="UniformToFill" Source="{Binding ImageUri}"/>
                    <Separator Width="20" Background="Transparent"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                        <TextBlock.Background>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding BackgroundColor}"/>
                        </TextBlock.Background>
                        <TextBlock.Foreground>
                            <SolidColorBrush Color="{Binding ForegroundColor}"/>
                        </TextBlock.Foreground>
                    </TextBlock>
                </DockPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>

This is what I have written in the code-behind
namespace MyTestApp.Views
{    
    public partial class MySortingView : UserControl
    {
        private Point _dragStartPoint;

        private T FindVisualParent<T>(DependencyObject child)
            where T : DependencyObject
        {
            var parentObject = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(child);
            if (parentObject == null)
                return null;
            T parent = parentObject as T;
            if (parent != null)
                return parent;
            return FindVisualParent<T>(parentObject);
        }

        public MySortingViewModel ViewModel { get; private set; }

        public MySortingView()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            lbItems.PreviewMouseMove += ListBox_PreviewMouseMove;

            var style = new Style(typeof(ListBoxItem));
            style.Setters.Add(new Setter(ListBoxItem.AllowDropProperty, true));
            style.Setters.Add(new EventSetter(ListBoxItem.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDownEvent,new MouseButtonEventHandler(ListBoxItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown)));
            style.Setters.Add(new EventSetter(ListBoxItem.DropEvent,new DragEventHandler(ListBoxItem_Drop)));
            lbItems.ItemContainerStyle = style;
        }

        private void ListBox_PreviewMouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Point point = e.GetPosition(null);
            Vector diff = _dragStartPoint - point;
            if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed &&
                (Math.Abs(diff.X) > SystemParameters.MinimumHorizontalDragDistance ||
                    Math.Abs(diff.Y) > SystemParameters.MinimumVerticalDragDistance))
            {
                var lb = sender as ListBox;
                var lbi = FindVisualParent<ListBoxItem>(((DependencyObject)e.OriginalSource));
                if (lbi != null)
                {
                    DragDrop.DoDragDrop(lbi, lbi.DataContext, DragDropEffects.Move);
                }
            }
        }
        private void ListBoxItem_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            _dragStartPoint = e.GetPosition(null);
        }

        private void ListBoxItem_Drop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender is ListBoxItem)
            {
                var source = e.Data.GetData(typeof(MyItem)) as MyItem;
                var target = ((ListBoxItem)(sender)).DataContext as MyItem;

                int sourceIndex = lbItems.Items.IndexOf(source);
                int targetIndex = lbItems.Items.IndexOf(target);

                Move(source, sourceIndex, targetIndex);

                lbItems.Items.Refresh();
            }
        }

        private void Move(MyItem source, int sourceIndex, int targetIndex)
        {
            ViewModel.Items.Swap(sourceIndex, targetIndex);
        }
        //using this event to get the view model data
        private void UserControl_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MySortingView view = sender as MySortingView;

            if (view != null)
            {
                ViewModel = (MySortingViewModel)view.DataContext;
            }
        }
    }
}

From this code I am able to get what I wanted which is the ability to reorder list box items but what I would like to do now is to take it a step above and add some feedback or some nice graphic that will show a "preview" to the user where the item is going to be placed based on the cursor position.
What are some of the steps I need to take in order to get started? Am I just missing a property in the xaml code that will enable the real-time feedback I am looking for? Many thanks in advance.

I would go with the more familiar and simpler "mover" pattern: select an item; click one of two buttons that moves an item up or down one position. No sliding, dragging, previewing. Works on all devices.
